# Cant putObject to s3 from ECS container

Tags: amazon-s3, containers, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I have setup an ECS task containing two containers. The containers are fully responsive to request, but they need to put some items into s3, but I get `Err foundAccessDenied: Access Denied`.

I have attached a new policy as following to `ecsTaskExecutionRole` role.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Also added the following env when creating docker images: `ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE=true`

What am I missing here that all the time get the AccessDenied error?!

Comment: try to simulate your roles with their [iam policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/).  Those seemed alright to me but I might have missed something, there are maybe roles that still needed for you to access s3 so you best bet is try the simulator.

Comment: Are you using VPC Gateway Endpoint for S3 or you are going through IGW to S3 from ECS?. First have your IAM role checked out as per above and then we can start looking at other causes.

Comment: What "Network Mode" is your Task configured for? For "Host Network Mode" use ECS_ENABLE_TASK_IAM_ROLE_NETWORK_HOST=true. Are you using an ECS optimized AMI? If not look into the "docker run --net=" command line option. If those don't help, check the metadata and verify that you actually have credentials.